# VBA SeleniumBasic - Clickables no longer work after missing one

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I built a very complex SeleniumBasic via VBA via Excel Addin setup that interacts with one of the leading ticketing system websites to scrap and populate data.  The system interacts with 90+ different fields/clickables with 3 different pages, 6 different tabs, and nested popups...deployed to 120 users who use the automations about 20 times per day.

*And it has been working flawlessly for over a year...*

We have just provisioned 20 more users on the same system, and their automations refuse to work.

Here is where I am at with my research:

- I am able to manually step through code on the new system and have it successfully go through the entire automation, so the issue probably has something to do with the speed VBA/Selenium is trying to interact with the website.
- Once the system is unable to find a field or clickable, it refuses to find any other ones after that.

  - The way the system is built in order to go as fast as possible is via standard VBA error handling.  It fails to find something, it goes to the error handler, the error handler says to wait for one second then try again.  Again, this system has been working flawlessly for over a year and is currently working on 120 user's systems.
  - To see if maybe Selenium was refusing to reload the clickable, I broke out the error handling from a Resume to a Resume Next, and then had a do while loop with a boolean flag to keep trying until it was successful, but after the first failure, it refused to find anything else, including different fields
- The one thing the 20 new users have in common is that they are all using v66 of Chrome, whereas all of the systems that are working have old copies of Chrome that are at least 9 months old

  - Thinking this might be an issue, I grabbed all of the ChromeDrivers and systematically went through one by one to test if we got a different performance with a different ChromeDriver, but all of the ChromeDrivers had the same error

So that is where I stand.  I'm wondering if there is some key insight I am missing or a workaround that will get newer versions of Chrome to retry the fields.  Or...do I need to try a VBA/Selenium tool other than SeleniumBasic to fix this.  Or...do I need to roll back these 20 users to older versions of Chrome.

Thanks for sharing your expertise.

```
''''Check to see if there are any aliases=================================
For AliasCheck = 2 To AliasCounter + 1
    If Hash = Sheets("Temp Subjects & Locations").Range("AY" & AliasCheck) Then
        AliasName = Sheets("Temp Subjects & Locations").Range("AY" & AliasCheck)
        AliasCount = AliasCount + 1
        AliasDisplayName = Sheets("Temp Subjects & Locations").Range("AZ" & AliasCheck)

        temp1 = ""
        temp2 = ""

        Call countryDictionary

        'drops the country back into Excel to later remove the dupes
        temp1 = Sheets("Temp Subjects & Locations").Range("BA" & AliasCheck)
        temp2 = dict(temp1)
        Sheets("Temp Subjects & Locations").Range("BG" & AliasCount + 1) = temp2

        ''''Click to add AKA's names
        iframeText = "iframe_win_" & AddParty
        robot.SwitchToDefaultContent
        robot.SwitchToFrame iframeText

        iframeTracker = iframeTracker + 1
        iframeText = "iframe_win_" & iframeTracker

        robot.SwitchToDefaultContent
        robot.SwitchToFrame iframeText
        robot.FindElementById("X_SUBJECT_ALTERNATE_NM.X_ALTERNATE_NM").SendKeys (AliasDisplayName)
        robot.FindElementById("dijit_form_Button_0").Click
    End If
Next AliasCheck
```

The AddParty variable is a way to track the number of the pop-up we came from.
The iFrameTracker variable is a way to track the number of the pop-up we are going to...the system sequentially numbers its pop-ups...instead of legible names...

The newer systems will make it down to the SendKeys and then decide not to work.  On a resume next, it will then refuse to find the OK button ("dijit_form_Button_0")

Here is the code I was playing around with to see if I could get it to retry using a "Resume Next" instead of a "Resume"

```
robot.FindElementById("X_SUBJECT_ALTERNATE_NM.X_ALTERNATE_NM").SendKeys (AliasDisplayName)           
Do While FailRetry = True
    FailRetry = False        
    robot.FindElementById("X_SUBJECT_ALTERNATE_NM.X_ALTERNATE_NM").SendKeys (AliasDisplayName)
Loop

errHandler4:
If errorCounter < 21 Then
    Application.wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    errorCounter = errorCounter + 1
    FailRetry = True
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox "Reached 20 second timeout.  Stopping processing."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: There is no code or HTML for us to go on. Can you narrow down a specific element which is always the cause? You can look at ways of looping until that is set, perhaps it needs to be scrolled into view? It may have a visible property/display that you can alter. Very difficult to know with just the above.

Comment: I have been able to get the system to fail in at least 5 different locations.  When manually stepping through the automation, if I hit the play button, it will quickly complete everything on the currently loaded screen and then die when it goes to navigate to a different area.  When running the system automatically it usually fails in one of the first three pop-ups, but it is inconsistent in where it fails, leading me to think that the speed is the issue.  I will post some code...

Comment: Is it finding robot.FindElementById("X_SUBJECT_ALTERNATE_NM.X_ALTERNATE_NM") ? Can you set a loop here, with timeout, until item is not nothing? Tedious if repeating though you could write a helper sub/function. This would help if it is a time-based problem.

Comment: I was playing around with that exact thing.  But it refused to find the link after failing the first time.  I will post some code...

Comment: What error message does it produce at this point? If you have an On Error Resume Next before the Set x = robot.FindElementById("X_SUBJECT_ALTERNATE_NM.X_ALTERNATE_NM") and On Error GoTo O after then it should keep trying within the Do ......Loop While X Is Nothing

Comment: There is no error message on this.  It just times out due to the error handling.  Now that you mention it, it seems like it would be a dandy idea to remove the error handling for a test and see what it is specifically complaining about...

Comment: Do you wait for a window dialog that you may track while waiting? You may track until the dialog is displayed if so. As in example, when we hit "Save As" In excel, that window dialog is shown.

Comment: Did you receive an error message in latest attempts?

Comment: Another post with no url to share. This sort of posts which are meant to lead to hypothesis are mostly available under `vba` tag.

Comment: Sorry there is no URL to share.  The website is in a secure system protected by unique user logins and in the client's system...there is no way to share the access with this community.

Comment: When I run the code without the error capturing, it tells me that the element doesn't exist.  When I hit debug and tell it to try again now that the pop-up has fully loaded, it again says that it doesn't exist and refuses to go any further.  On manually cycling through the code, it works without error, and in the old system, Chrome v61 instead of v66 it works without error.  This leads me back to thinking that speed or newer system compatibility is the issue, but that doesn't get me any closer to a solution.